# Reverse Engineering a database with EntityFramework 6 using ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

EntityFramework Core's `Scaffold-Db` is one of the worst things I have ever experience as anytime I install the package in a new project, I experience new bugs and errors.

I have decided to move backward and use EF 6 for now, but is there any way to reverse engineer an existing database using EF 6 automatically in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: your question is not clear. what did you mean here `but is there any way to reverse engineer an existing database using EF 6 automatically in ASP.Net Core` ?

Answer (score -1):

Use the "EF reverse Poco" template which you can install via Tools, Extensions and Updates in Visual Studio

Comment: What/where is "EF reverse Poco" template?

Comment: @GertArnold Updated my reply

Comment: This is built-in now into the EF tools for VS. Entity Framework Power Tools (if that is what you mean) is supported up to VS2013 and it is still marked as beta. I wouldn't recommend this tool anymore.

Comment: No, I mean The EF reverse poco template